# No audio or Bluetooth after updating to Windows 10 2004 (Boot Camp)

Tags: macos, bootcamp

I have an iMac 2017 27” and I use Windows on an external SSD and after updating to Windows 10 build 2004, no matter what I do, I can get audio or Bluetooth to work.

On the bluetooth’s case there’s no driver. The audio allows me to control volume and I can see the VU meters going up and down like it it was working, except for the fact that I can’t hear anything.

I’ve tried to change the output several times without any luck.

Anyone have any idea on how to fix this?
Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried installing the latest BootCamp drivers? https://support.apple.com/downloads/boot-camp

Comment: Yes I have. I’ve tried using a mac and also using Brigadier.

Comment: Never even heard of Brigadier. Remove the drivers *completely* in device manager. Use Apple Software update to download any updated bootcamp drivers. If it doesn't find any then download the latest, extract the drivers from the .exe/.zip file and install manually. Your Mac *is supported* with Win 10 under bootcamp so Apple makes the drivers. I'll bet the issue is more "driver hell" within Windows itself, and that is no fun at all.

Comment: Installing manually did the trick. What Boot Camp basically did was to not install any driver for Bluetooth and install the wrong one for audio. After I’ve cleaned up everything that Boot Camp did and installed every single driver manually, everything worked after a reboot. Thank you so much for your help! I would never have guessed that Boot Camp was such a terrible piece of software. I could swear this was due to incompatibility or something. Thanks again!

Comment: Honestly it is not so much BootCamp, it's windows. I've been supporting it since the 3.1 days and nothing that Windows does surprises me any more. It is an utter *MESS* and the only thing that saves it is that it is a *better mess* than the previous version, and so on. This is why I only use Windows when I absolutely have to and all personal computers are Macs. They aren't perfect, they're just **better.**

Comment: I have to agree with you on that. I feel the same way about Android. I think Windows and Android are more capable in terms of software, but they both are a mess.